# display InputFormSection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, display-form, style-library

Can we hide an wssuc:InputFormSection ??
I have a wssuc:InputFormSection made for adding items and it's only shown when you click on add link as the code shows :

```
<Table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
<tr>
<td>
    <wssuc:InputFormSection ID="QueryNameSection" runat="server" >
            <template_inputformcontrols>
                <wssuc:InputFormControl ID="QueryNameControl" runat="server">
                    <Template_Control>                                           
                        <div class="ms-authoringcontrols">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="QueryNameTBx" runat="server"  Width="265px" Height="15px">
                            </asp:TextBox><br />
                            </div>
                    </Template_Control>
                </wssuc:InputFormControl>
            </template_inputformcontrols>
    </wssuc:InputFormSection>
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="8">
    <wssuc:InputFormSection ID="JointListsSection" runat="server" Description="" >
        <template_inputformcontrols>
            <wssuc:InputFormControl ID="JointListsControl" runat="server">
                <Template_Control>  
                    <div>
                        <span style="position: relative; width: 10px; display: inline-block; height: 10px;
                        overflow: hidden" class="s4-clust">
                        <img style="position: absolute; top: -128px !important; left: 0px !important" alt=""
                        src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" />
                        </span>
                        <a  class="ms-addnew" onclick="AddList(); return false;" href="#" ><%#PROGED.SharePoint.MultiQuery.Constants.Resx.AddNewList%></a>
                    </div>
                </Template_Control>
            </wssuc:InputFormControl>
        </template_inputformcontrols>
    </wssuc:InputFormSection>
</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td colspan="8">
    <wssuc:InputFormSection ID="AddListSection" runat="server" >
        <template_inputformcontrols>
            <wssuc:InputFormControl ID="AddListControl" runat="server">
                <Template_Control>  
                    <asp:Panel ID="JointLists" Visible="true" runat="server" style="color:Red;" >
                        <div class="ms-authoringcontrols">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ListsDDL" runat="server" Width="265px" Height="20px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListsDDL_OnLoad" >
                            </asp:DropDownList><br />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ms-authoringcontrols">
                            <asp:table ID="TableFieldsControls" runat="server" >
                                <asp:TableHeaderRow CssClass="ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr" >
                                <asp:TableHeaderCell Width="20px"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                <asp:TableHeaderCell Width="100px"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                <asp:TableHeaderCell Width="100px"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                            </asp:table>
                        </div>

                    </asp:Panel>

                </Template_Control>
            </wssuc:InputFormControl>
        </template_inputformcontrols>
    </wssuc:InputFormSection>
</td>
</tr> 
</Table>
```

so i was wondering can I do something like this in my javascript function :

### Heading

Comment: perfect. works like a champ!!!